# Godot 4 not processing collision?

Tags: godot, godot4

I'm having an issue with something I'm making in Godot, where I have an area2D on_body_entered function in my player character, which detects the player CharacterBody2D, but not the enemy CharacterBody2D whenever it passes through the player. What could the issue be?

I tried using:

func _on_area_2d_body_entered(body):
print("hit")

I expected it to print "hit" once for when the player starts, and another time for when the player and enemy touch, but it only printed the first time.

Comment: `collision_layer` and `collision_mask`

Comment: I think it is an issue with colission layers, but I can't tell what it is. If I put the player and enemy on the same collision layer, the collision works, but if I put them on different layers and use masks it doesn't.

Comment: Those are of the player and the enemy, look at the ones of the area.

Comment: The layers and masks are the same for the character body and the area 2D.

Comment: And that one works

Comment: No, for some reason. Maybe it would help if i told you the layers and masks for the player and enemy. The player is on layer 1 and has a mask on layer 2. The enemy is on layer 2 and has masks on layers 1 and 3.

Comment: You said in the question the area detects the player but not the enemy. Now it seems to be the opposite. You say the player has mask on layer 2, and the area has the same mask, so also on layer 2. This means that area will only detect bodies on layer 2. Which would be the enemy. The gist of it is: put on the mask of the area what it should detect.

Comment: I am actually having the same issue.  Where I have a box spawning an item, and the box is triggering the collision with the item.  I have them both set not to interact with one another.